# Pass data to Python multiprocessing.Pool worker processes

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to leverage `Pool.map(func, itr)` to increase performance of a program, and I need `func` to access a **very large** dictionary called `cache` so it can do a cache lookup.

The `cache` stores "*the binary representations of each of the first `2**16` integers*".

```
cache = {i: bin(i) for i in range(2**16 - 1)}
```

The responsibility of `func` is to count up the number of `1s`, or *on-bits* in the binary representation of the `int` passed to it:

```
def func(i: int) -> int:
    return cache[i].count("1")
```

I want to do something like the following:

```
with Pool(8) as pool:
    counts = pool.map(func, [i for i in range(2**16-1)])
```

But how do I make the `cache` object available to `func` in each worker subprocess?

Answer (score 7):

#### A Naive Solution

One can "out-clever" themselves with the following recipe found across the internet:

```
import functools

cache = {i: bin(i) for i in range(2**16 - 1)}

def func(i: int, cache: Dict[int, str]) -> int:
    return cache[i].count("1")


with Pool(8) as pool:
    # Bind 'cache' to 'func' and pass the partial to map()
    counts = pool.map(functools.partial(func, cache=cache),
                      [i for i in range(2**16-1)])
```

This works...until you realize that **this is actually slower than running w/o parallelization!** You end up spending more for serialization/deserialization of your big `cache` than the ROI you get from parallelizing. See [Stuck in a Pickle](https://thelaziestprogrammer.com/python/a-multiprocessing-pool-pickle) for a more in-depth explanation.

#### A Correct Solution

The current "best-practice" for copying data to a Pool worker subprocess is, in one way or another, make the variable `global`. The pattern looks as follows:

```
cache = {i: bin(i) for i in range(2**16 - 1)}

def func(i: int) -> int:
    return global_cache[i].count("1")


def make_global(cache: Dict[int, str]) -> None:
    # Declare 'global_cache' to be Global
    global global_cache
    # Update 'global_cache' with a value, now *implicitly* accessible in func
    global_cache = cache


with Pool(8, initializer=make_global, initargs=(cache,)) as pool:
    counts = pool.map(func, [i for i in range(2**16-1)])
```

This same pattern can be applied to object-oriented code, swapping **class attributes** for **global variables**. [We buy a bit more encapsulation this way.](https://thelaziestprogrammer.com/python/multiprocessing-pool-a-global-solution)

A note on the `global` keyword inside of `make_global()'s` function body:

> The `global` keyword above declares a variable named `global_cache`. From
>   the point that this is declared, until the end of the program,
>   `global_cache` will be accessible with **global scope**, despite it being
>   declared within a function's scope (*though this won't get "globalized"
>   until a subprocess is forked, isolating the global scope to the worker
>   process*).

#### A (Proposed) New Solution

There is a 3rd option, though it lives in a `CPython` fork [buried deep, deep in a github repository](https://github.com/seanharr11/cpython/commit/38510c8231bac9f0213f0e43aed59aff8546d850).

This fork proposes a feature that allows you to do the following:

```
cache = {i: bin(i) for i in range(2**16 - 1)}

def func(i: int, initret: Dict[int, str]) -> int:
    cache = initret  # Re-assign var for illustrative/readability purposes
    return cache[i].count("1")


def identity(cache: Dict[int, str]) -> Dict[int, str]:
    return cache


with Pool(8, initializer=identity, initargs=(cache,)) as pool:
    counts = pool.map(func, [i for i in range(2**16-1)])
```

Though it is a small change, it skirts around using globals, and allows for a more readable "flow of data" between parent and worker processes. [More on this here](https://thelaziestprogrammer.com/python/multiprocessing-pool-expect-initret-proposal).

Essentially, the return value of `initializer` (`identity()` above) is passed to `func` (as a **kwarg** named `initret`) each time `func` is called in the worker process.

**Note:** *I am the author of all linked blog posts above.*

Comment: Since it has been some time since you've posted this answer, can you update if anything has changed since then? For the latest release of python 3.7 or even 3.8?
Since, from what I understand the "Proposed" solution is not based on the official python release, right?